# What is causing delay in my program? Reading serial data and parsing. (ESP32: Arduino IDE)

Tags: arduino, gps, esp32, nmea

In my test program, I have an unexpected delay (approx 100 ms).
I am trying to read data from GPS (as NMEA sentence) and parse it.
Currently, the program reads the data and if it is NMEA sentence, it try to parse it. The problem is, that I get a delay of approx 100ms between some of the messages.

The baude rate of the GPS is 9600, could this cause the problems?

My approach is to parse GGA sentence, and resend to different serial port (USB) a modified custom sentence with added sensor data as soon as possible (should looks like originally from GPS - so synchronized)

My output looks like this:
[Output from program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYC01.png)

```
13:38:31.306 -> $GPGSV,3,1,10,02,25,125,,06,28,083,,12,79,312,,15,05,189,,0*6E
13:38:31.306 -> $GPGSV,3,1,10,02,25,125,,06,28,083,,12,79,312,,15,05,189,,0*6E
13:38:31.306 -> 5
13:38:31.306 -> $GPGSV,3,2,10,17,11,042,,19,32,049,,24,59,149,,25,36,270,,0*60
13:38:31.410 -> $GPGSV,3,2,10,17,11,042,,19,32,049,,24,59,149,,25,36,270,,0*60
13:38:31.410 -> 112
13:38:31.410 -> $GPGSV,3,3,10,29,04,210,,32,29,303,,0*62
13:38:31.410 -> $GPGSV,3,3,10,29,04,210,,32,29,303,,0*62
13:38:31.410 -> 3
13:38:31.410 -> $GLGSV,3,1,10,69,00,219,,70,23,270,,71,21,324,,73,05,293,,0*75
13:38:31.544 -> $GLGSV,3,1,10,69,00,219,,70,23,270,,71,21,324,,73,05,293,,0*75
13:38:31.544 -> 113
13:38:31.544 -> $GLGSV,3,2,10,78,10,101,,79,57,075,,80,51,314,,81,56,083,,0*72
13:38:31.544 -> $GLGSV,3,2,10,78,10,101,,79,57,075,,80,51,314,,81,56,083,,0*72
13:38:31.544 -> 7
```

The first sentence is printed directly after the byte has been received. The second sentence is printed as a String after the full sentence has been received.

Here is my code:

```
#define RXD2 13
#define TXD2 12
#define SERIAL_SIZE_RX  1024    // used in Serial.setRxBufferSize()

bool bNMEAstarted = false;
String NMEAsent;

unsigned long currentTime, lastTime;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(15);

  //GPS serial
  Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);
  delay(150);
  //Serial2.setRxBufferSize(SERIAL_SIZE_RX);  //increase buffer size to 1024 bytes
  currentTime = millis();
  lastTime = currentTime;
}

void loop() {
  receiveFromGPS();
}


void receiveFromGPS(){
  byte incomByte1 = 0;
  if (Serial2.available()>0){
    incomByte1 = Serial2.read();
    Serial.write(incomByte1);
    
    // Parsing NMEA sentence
    if (incomByte1 == '$') {        //means it is NMEA sentece
      bNMEAstarted = true;
      NMEAsent = "";                //empty the string
    }

    if (bNMEAstarted) {
      NMEAsent += (char)incomByte1;       //add every character to NMEA sentence
      if (incomByte1 == 10) {             //ASCII(10) <LF> (Linefeed) ends the message
        bNMEAstarted = false;
        //do parsing after the end on sentence
        parseNMEA(NMEAsent);
      }
    }
  }
}


void parseNMEA(String sNMEA) {
  //if (sNMEA.substring(3,6) == "GGA") {      // GGA Message found

    //only print every NMEA sentence and time between each measurements
    Serial.print(sNMEA);
    currentTime = millis();
    Serial.println(currentTime-lastTime);
  //} 
  lastTime = currentTime;
}
```

Comment: Hi Marrek, please copy and paste the output as text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: How exactly do you measure the delay? The timestamps from serial port monitor?

Comment: Tarmo - Will modify the test. Thank you. 
I measure time between each prints of the String (in the parseNMEA() function). 
Also, the timestamp from serial monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The longer GGA sentence is 64 bytes long. At 9600 baud a single byte takes roughly 1 ms to transmit. If your GPS spits out GGA sentences without any delay between them, then it's expected to receive a sentence every 64 ms - which is what you have on average.

The confusing part here is probably the fact that sometimes the read seems to happen very quickly (<10 ms) and sometimes very slowly (>100 ms). This is caused by the UART's buffers. The UART in ESP32 has a 128 B FIFO buffer on the receive side, which receives the incoming bytes and doesn't give them to you before [one of two conditions](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18069#p67509) occurs:

1. buffer is nearly full (exact amount not documented) or
2. buffer is not full (but holds some data) and a RX timeout occurs (exact timeout value not documented).

This creates the situation where you'll eventually get your data, but it's a bit... choppy. I'm sorry to say I don't know how to fix this, as the UART buffer cannot be bypassed easily (or, at least, there's no official documentation on how to do it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is some cheap GPS module from china, which should be working on 2 Hz. (so every 500 ms output all NMEA sentences). - I have this module only for testing my code. 
I will try to connect some other GPS unit and will see. 
What is causing my headache is that sometimes there is no delay (as I want it to be - would work perfectly) and sometimes there is 100 ms delay. 
Serial.Available() is returning how many bytes are there in the buffer, and Serial.Read() is taking one byte, and removing it from buffer. That would mean, that the reading will be made until the end

Comment: It's impossible to have 0 delay. 64 bytes will take 64 ms to transmit over the serial at 9600 baud - you can't get rid of that without switching to a higher baud rate (would be around 6 ms at 115200). And there's not that much difference between 64 ms or 100 ms. As for the Arduino Serial class - yes, that's how it's *supposed to work*. But running on ESP32 the Arduino code can't escape how the hardware buffer and ESP IDF on ESP32 really works.

Comment: Yeah, but you can see there is a delay between I read the data with writing bytes to serial, and parsing. That is what I do not understand. It means, that the sentence (data) has come to program buffer. 
Sometimes it is without delay, sometimes it is with approx 100ms delay.

Comment: The Arduino `Serial` object does not give you direct access to UART. Received bytes are stored first in the UART's RX buffer. You don't see it because it's ESP's hardware, and you can't read it before the buffer gets flushed. The data becomes available to `Serial` only after the buffer is flushed. The (arguably not so great) logic of flushing the RX buffer ensures that while there's a continuous stream of incoming data, it will try to fill up most of the 128 B buffer. That logic is hidden somewhere in the lower layers of the ESP IDF UART driver, and there's no obvious way to change it.

Comment: Okay, I've changes GPS module to Drotek Ublox M8N. Set up output to 8 Hz, with only GGA, RMC and VTG messages, and set baud rate to 115200. I should get message every 125ms. Most of the time I do (135-145 ms), but sometimes it appears to be doubled (250 ms). When comparing UTC time in GGA sentence, it appeares some of the sentences are lost. What could cause that?

Comment: Maybe there is a possibility to modify buffer threshold? Or to decrease the FIFO buffer size? 
Or is the problem with my code with loosing data? Should I use some kind of interrupt to see if I have new data on serial? a timer interrupt?

Comment: Strange, I wouldn't expect that. An easy thing to try is to read everything in the serial port in a single loop. Changing this line `if (Serial2.available()>0){` to `while (Serial2.available()>0){` should do it.

Comment: Yes I had to do that. When I tried to put a larger delay in loop (50 ms), the data processing was slow, and then it would just went mad.